# Array(char) in Java

Tags: java, массивы

cell-массив символов '*','S','G'. Мне нужно чтобы внутри for он проверял что в массиве только те 3 символа, если один отсутствует то должен trust=false. Я сделал(код наверху) так , но она не работает.Помогите!?

```
package maze;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise02_Full {
    private static final String dataPath = "mazedata-2.txt";
    private static char[][] cell;
    private static int maxRow = 0;      // These are the height and width of the maze
    private static int maxCol = 0;
    private static final int WALL = -1;     // These constants are the encoding used to represent the maze
    private static final int START = -2;    // A zero and positive values are pathways.  A positive value
    private static final int GOAL = -3;     // specifies how many times the MazeRunner has left this position

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(dataPath));
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
            maxCol = s.nextInt();
            maxRow = s.nextInt();
            cell = new char[maxCol][maxRow];


                        Scanner l;
                        for (int r=0;r<maxRow;r++) {
                            line = scanner.nextLine();
                            l = new Scanner(line);
                            l.useDelimiter("");

                            int c = 0;
            //grab the data from each line


                            while (l.hasNext() && c<20){
                                char [] temp =  l.next().toCharArray();
                                cell[r][c++] = temp[0];
                            }
                        }
                        boolean trust = true;
                        char[] p ={'*','S','G'}; 
                        for(int i = 0; i<cell.length;i++){
                            for(int j = 0; j<cell.length;j++){
                                if(cell[i][j] == '*' || cell[i][j] == 'S' || cell[i][j] == 'G') { 
                                    trust = true;
                                    //System.out.println(cell[i][j]+" "+i+j);
                                }else {
                                    trust = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(trust==true){
                            System.out.println(mazeToString());
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Ошибка");
                           }

            //System.out.println(mazeToString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Create a String representation of the maze
     */
    private static String mazeToString(){
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxCol; j++)
                str += cell[i][j];
            str += '\n';
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Нужно проверить, что присутствуют все символы? Приведите пример, для которого приведенный цикл не работает.

Comment: Нужно проверить то что  3 символа существует. Если одного нет то trust=false.Если есть другой символ то trust=false

Answer (score 1):

Вы не зайдете в тело `if`, когда `cell[i][j] = '*'` или `S` или `G`, так как `cell[i][j] != '*'` и т.д. вернет false и в итоге будет false. А зайдете в тело, когда ваша ячейка не будет равна ни `*`, ни `S`, ни `G`.

Comment: Поетому нужно делать либо так:
`if(cell[i][j]!='*' || cell[i][j]!='S' || cell[i][j]!='G')`, либо так
`if(cell[i][j]=='*' && cell[i][j]=='S' && cell[i][j]=='G')`

Comment: что делать тогда?

Comment: Мне больше нравиться вот этот - `if(cell[i][j]=='*' && cell[i][j]=='S' && cell[i][j]=='G') {} else {trust = false}`

Comment: Че то он всеравно так работает

Comment: А у вас матрица `cell` квадратная? Просто для `i`, `j` у вас одинаковое условие: `i<cell.length`, `j<cell.length`.

Comment: Если нет, то нужно так: `i<cell.length`, `j<cell[0].length`. И нужно убедиться, что размер внутреннего массива не меняется!

Comment: Да она на 20 20

Comment: if(cell[i][j]=='*' && cell[i][j]=='S' && cell[i][j]=='G') . Денис, прошу пояснить мне необразованому в каком случаи условие вернет true? Если у нас в ячейке стоить "*", то первая часть условия вернет true, а остальные false, так как один символ не может равнятся сразу трем символам *, S, G

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych, да, я не правильно понял условия. Думал, что матрица должна быть заполнена только *, S, G. Не понял, что она обязательно должна быть заполнена всеми символами.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, или c помощью стримов

```
boolean allMatch = Stream.of(cell)
            .map(String::new)
            .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
            .allMatch(c -> c == (int) '*' || c == (int)'S' || c == (int)'G');
System.out.println(allMatch);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public boolean check(char[][] arr) {
boolean trust1, trust2, trust3 = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                  if(!trust1 && arr[i][j] == '*'){
                     trust1 = true;
                  }

                  if(!trust2 && arr[i][j] == 'S'){
                     trust2 = true;
                  }

                  if(!trust3 && arr[i][j] == 'G'){
                     trust3 = true;
                  }

                }
            }
            return trust1 && trust2 && trust3;
        }
```

Comment: как отправить arr[][] в метод?

Comment: boolean trust = check(cell);

Comment: все нормально работает?

Comment: нет, не могу передать

Comment: напишите мне на почту данные для подключения через теам вивер martsinkevych@gmail.com

Comment: у меня просто теам вивер нету

Comment: выводит ошибку изза того что мой массив static, a method не статичныйю

Comment: сделай метод статическим, почему он статический?

Answer (score 0):

Вот все работает :)

```
public boolean check(char[][] arr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                if(arr[i][j] == '*' || arr[i][j] == 'S' || arr[i][j] == 'G') {

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Извини) но она все равно не выходит)

Comment: Что не выходит?

Comment: if(trust==true){
                            System.out.println(mazeToString());
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Ошибка");
                           }

Comment: я вот так проверяю.Но она всеравно выводит ошибку

Comment: Метод возвращает `true`, если все ячейки равны либо `*`, либо `S`, либо `G`. Иначе возвращает `false`. И это точно, я у себя проверил. Может у тебя опять какая-то ошибка, покажи весь код.

Comment: я добавил весь код на вопрос

Comment: Конечно не будет работать потому, что последняя ячейка может вернуть `true`, а может и `false`. Ты берешь одну переменную и постоянно меняешь ее значение, то есть в итоге ты просто проверяешь последнюю ячейку. Нужно либо поместить проверку в отдельный метод, как это сделал я, или убрать строчку `trust = true`. Но, опять же, лучше не пихать все в один метод, а вот такие вот логические отступы помещать в отдельный метод.

Comment: Нет, всеравно неправильно